# Azure Devops - How to extract Test Run Id and Test Case Id during test execution in a release

Tags: azure-devops

I was hoping I might be able add attachments to test cases in a release during execution, but it doesn't look like the data is available in the api at that point.

This is what I'm trying....

- Release Id is copied to a file at start of release
- Visual Studio Test task starts
- Code within the VS Test task finds the release Id (I'm not using MSTest so can't pass it in as a run time variable) and attempts to call the **https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_apis/test/runs** endpoint to find the currently running test run id based on release id.
- Always returns a count of 0 whilst the test run/task is still executing

At which point is this information available in the api? Is it only when a particular task has finished?

If I can't get the test run id or test case id whilst a test is running, it's going to be a really fiddly job trying to retrospectively attach them, matching up the attachment with the particular test case.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by only querying the api after a release task has finished. My test run and test cases appeared in the api after the test run had finished, with the release still running.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?? Newbie here.